# Deploy C# application with crystal report on production server

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

I downloaded developer edition of crystal report for vs2019 and my crystal report works fine locally but now I have to deploy the application to production server . My question is developer edition will work or do i need to install run time version of crystal report on server?? and what is the way to deploy crystal report on server?? Please help

Comment: You should install the runtime on the server.  SAP asks you to install the run time MSI as administrator & you can find a how to here https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-run-msi-file-as-administrator-from-command-prompt-in-windows/

Comment: @RajeshThampi with runtime version it's not working into production site . I installed SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio (SP27) runtime engine for .NET framework MSI (64-bit) still not works .. also tried with 32 bit .. nothing working ..

Comment: Please remove the Crystal Reports from your Server, restart the server and re-install 64Bit runtime. Check your application pool settings. If it is allowed to execute 32Bit applications, create a new application pool for your application and assign. Try to load the page with Crystal Reports

Comment: @RajeshThampi it worked :-) Thank you . CR runtime version works into production site but with a small adjustment like I have to change "platform target" from AnyCPU to x64 that's all

Comment: glad to read that you were able to get it done. My problems were totally different, one of the components wouldn't load and I figured out that my application pool had 32bit execution enabled for a PHP application. I had to create a new pool specific for 64bit Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 0):

it worked. CR runtime version works into production site but with a small adjustment like I have to change "platform target" from AnyCPU to x64 that's all . :-)